# Detect state change in webview

Tags: android, webview

I have loaded a url in webview, when I click on a button a new view appears in the webview without changing the url. Is there any way to capture this state change in the webview?

Answer (score 2):

yeah checkout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String) using js interface is the only way to register changes in the webview